# Calculate date with PHP

Tags: php, time

How can I set a date range value for each week that gets updated dynamically as time goes on. I want to start the week on Monday and end on Sunday.

Example output would need to be 2011-10-24,2011-10-31

Using the below I am only getting the date of the month vs YYYY-MM-DD

```
<?php  
   $today = getdate();
   $weekStartDate = $today['mday'] - $today['mon']+1;
   $weekEndDate = $today['mday'] - $today['wday']+7;
   echo "week start date:".$weekStartDate;
   echo "<br/>";
   echo "week end date:".$weekEndDate;
?>
```

Comment: Have a look at PHP's DateTime class. http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Comment: The week of Oct. 24th is from the 24th to the 30th, not the 31st.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, use `DateTime`.

```
<?php
$dt = new DateTime('Monday this week'); // yes, DateTime is that awesome
$interval = new DateInterval('P6D'); // 6 days
?>

<dl>
    <dt>Week start date:</dt>
    <dd><?php echo $dt->format('Y-m-d') ?></dd>

    <dt>Week end date:</dt>
    <dd><?php echo $dt->add($interval)->format('Y-m-d') ?></dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of `date('N')` (day of the week, 1 - 7):

```
$monday = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n'), date('j') - (date('N') - 1));
$sunday = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n'), date('j') - (date('N') - 7));

echo date('Y-m-d', $monday);
echo date('Y-m-d', $sunday);
```